# create listview on fragment custom drawer

Tags: android, listview, fragment

i have trouble with my code,
im trying to create a new listview on my fragment.
im using custom drawer.

this my code and my error on line 53. 
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_schedule, container, false);  //ERROR CODE HERE

this my complete code.

```
package com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Blackcustomzier on 10/2/14.
 */
public class FragmentSchedule extends ListFragment {


    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] {
            "India",
            "Pakistan",
            "Sri Lanka",
            "China",
            "Bangladesh",
            "Nepal",
            "Afghanistan",
            "North Korea",
            "South Korea",
            "Japan"
    };

    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] currency = new String[]{
            "Indian Rupee",
            "Pakistani Rupee",
            "Sri Lankan Rupee",
            "Renminbi",
            "Bangladeshi Taka",
            "Nepalese Rupee",
            "Afghani",
            "North Korean Won",
            "South Korean Won",
            "Japanese Yen"
    };

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("ZZZ", "ada di oncreateView");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_schedule, container, false);
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
            hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = {R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

this my fragment_layout_schedule

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/country_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi.FragmentSchedule"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this the catlog error

```
10-02 07:59:42.207    2103-2103/com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at com.example.blackcustomzier.skripsi.FragmentSchedule.onCreateView(FragmentSchedule.java:53)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:861)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1137)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4746)
```

thanks before

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and the fragment_layout_schedule.xml?

Comment: @sunil i have attach my fragment_layout_schedule.xml

Comment: @user2103379 the error on line 53.. "View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_schedule, container, false);"

Comment: Again what is the error? Is it an exception, a null pointer exception or what..you must have seen that in logcat right?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to expand a layout that does not contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list". You need to have this object in your layout xml. What you are trying to do is to inflate a regular fragment and map the list fragment to this but the thing is that there is no backing ListView object to map your ListFragment to.

Please see the description at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html on how to create custom views for your list fragments.